# Have border-radius cover inner divs

Tags: css

I have a Coda slider on one webpage (hand-crafted, not using the plugin, but that's irrelevant) and the outer div has a border-radius.

A bunch of inner divs have background colors, but they stick out on top of the corners when I want them to be BEHIND the rounded corner.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It is working with Firefox 3.6.11 with overflow: hidden.

Comment: Not working for me in 3.6.14.  What OS are you on? Does [the image on this page](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/rounded-corners.html) have rounded or square corners for you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found that WebKit would crop everything if I put `overflow: hidden` on the element, but Gecko wouldn't (see [my blog post for code and screenshots](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/2009/07/05/adventures-in-web-3-0-part-2-css-3?blog=2)).  The best I could do in Gecko was either put a border radius in the inner div too, or add a margin/padding to the wrapper div so that the inner divs sat below the corners.

Comment: So this is the only way then?

Comment: I suspect Gecko really ought to respect the overflow: hidden, but it's not fully implemented yet.  It's hard to say either way until the spec is finalised though.

Comment: I asked a question on the MDC wiki and Jürgen Jeka pointed me at the defect: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=459144

Comment: Found a way to get rounded corners in Firefox using SVG clipping: http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/2009/09/02/firefox-img-rounded-corners-svg?blog=2  Tested on image elements, ought to work for any content.

Comment: Works in IE10 dev preview as well (so maybe even 9 - have not tested)

Answer (score 20):

If you apply position:static to the element with overflow:hidden you will achieve the results you are looking for.

Check this out: [overflow:hidden, border-radius and position:absolute](http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/04/overflowhidden-border-radius-and.html)

Comment: this happens to be the reason. what looks like a solution to me is wrapping a div with position:static (or leave default) inside the position:absolute div.