# CSS rounded corners on img in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, rounded-corners

The problem is quite simple, but I spent too much time searching for answer. I'd appreciate if someone can throw a little light on the problem.

The CSS `-moz-border-radius` works with a `div`, but I'm trying to make it work on `img` tags.

`-webkit-border-radius` works flawlessly on `img` in Chromium.

I have also tried to wrap the `img` in a `div`, which has rounded corners and uses `overflow: hidden;`. It works in Chromium, but no hope in Firefox.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/css3-firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image. Seems like it is just not implemented yet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could put the image as a background of a div then have that div have rounded corners

Comment: Great hack. Thank you so much, i have completely forgot on background image. This will also solve problem with khtml based browsers.
@ Koning Baard XIV
I don't understand, what does it means Semantics?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which can help you to solve this problem

http://learneveryday.net/css/css-round-corner-menu-with-image/

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to create a radius for the corners of the animated gif at the top of this page http://annsummersbysara.co.uk.

```
<div class="slider">
  <a href="http://annsummersbysara.co.uk/party">
    <img style="border: 0px solid ; width: 687px; height: 150px;" 
         alt="Click here to book an Ann Summers Party" 
         title="Click here to book an Ann Summers Party"
         src="images/new_top_banner.gif">
  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

And this is the css for the div.

```
.slider{
    width:          687px;
    height:         150px;
    border:         2px #e5e5e5 solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius:      8px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    margin-top:     5px;
    overflow:       hidden;
    text-align:     center;
}
```

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your code fragment, Jonathan. This question was originally asked back in 2009, and in the intervening 3 years, Firefox has been updated such that "`img` in a `div` with `overflow:hidden`" works, which is what the original poster tried and failed to do. So the original problem is a non-issue anymore; remember to check the dates of questions you answer if you're searching deep in the bowels of StackOverflow.

Comment: @MidnightLightning +1 for **deep** digging. One has to admire the persistence. There should be a badge for such a thing. :)

Comment: @Chamster Thanks! You can actually +1 comments if you like... (hover and click the up arrow) ;)

Comment: @MidnightLightning Sure thing. But does it give you extra reputation? I don't think I get anything extra when people arrow up my comments. Only questions/answers...

Comment: @Chamster True, I did not get extra reputation for that. Though I didn't get any reputation for you just saying "+1" either. I guess it's good to do both just for leaving the visual upvote for future visitors, and commenting on it if you want to not be anonymous?