# firefox img rounded borders without using div background

Tags: firefox, css, rounded-corners

It's a known bug that -moz-border-radius doesnt work on images in firefox. What's a way to get this functionality without resorting to putting the image as a background on a rounded div?

Comment: Looks like this is fixed on Firefox 4.

Comment: Doesn't mean no one will use ff3 anymore =[

Comment: I think you'll have to put it in a container of some sort. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current Firefox [you can use SVG filters](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/2009/09/02/firefox-img-rounded-corners-svg?blog=2).  Have an SVG file `clip.svg` like this:

```
<svg:svg height="0">
    <svg:clipPath id="c1" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <svg:rect x="0" y="0" rx="0.05" ry="0.05" width="1" height="1"/>
    </svg:clipPath>
</svg:svg>
```

And apply it in CSS like this:

```
.target { clip-path: url(clip.svg#c1); }
```