# Rounded Corners on Images in FireFox 3.6.15+ still not working?

Tags: firefox, rounding, css

Greatly connected peoples on the web,
For my rounding of corners I have a problem on Firefox . I thought that prehistoric problem was solved byt on my firefox 3.6.15 its stil doesnt round the corner on images. Works all nicely in IE 9 beta and Safari and chrome too, however on my Win 7 64 bit the corners appear straight perfect rectangular without any hint of rounding on FF.

```
img#thmb { /* thumbnails */
    width:  200px;
    height: 200px;

    border-radius:         8px;
    -moz-border-radius:    8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong causing round corners to work on all my testing browsers correctly, except my only one favourite browser.... FireFox.
Thanks for hints and insight fix-up code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox -moz-border-radius won't crop out image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the way the `<img>` tags are implemented in the Gecko Engine, Firefox currently doesn't support `border-radius` on `<img>` tags (As of 3.x branch, Gecko 1.9.x).

This is a known bug.

However, in Firefox 4 (Gecko 2), rounded corners now clip content and images (if  `overflow : visible`  is not set). [[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius)

This bug required a major engine rewrite which is what the Mozilla team is doing with Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1):

For All browser compatibility you can apply Jquery for this

1. Download jquery https://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.09
2. Apply jquery.js and corner.js in your html code
3. Call corner function in $(document).ready() function

Code look like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.corner.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
round_corner { background: #666666; border:1px solid #000000; width:200px; height:150px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(.round_corner).corner()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my_div" class="round_corner"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For demo you can visit http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Answer (score 1):

To get rounded borders to images in old Firefox you need to add some padding to the `<img>` and a background color. It might be ugly depending how your design is, and they will basicly be just extended round borders wrapping the image, but in plain CSS it's the easiest way.