# -moz-border-radious does not work on images in firefox ... why? (related to css3)

Tags: image, firefox, xhtml, css, rounded-corners

-moz-border-radious does not work on image element (mean  in html) in firefox ... why? (related to css3)

i test some way for solving that such as make a container for that image and changing the radious of container / not help !

thanks for attention

best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox -moz-border-radius won't crop out image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image)

Comment: Also, are you sure you spelled it correctly? It's `-moz-border-radius` not `-moz-border-radious`.

Comment: works fine in FF4. see http://jsfiddle.net/wZybc/3/ FF4 doesn't even need the -moz- prefix anymore.

Comment: thanks for answers / yes , i used the right syntax / however does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 3 treats foreground images as being in front of the border. This results in the effect that you're seeing. It doesn't affect any other browsers, including Firefox 4.

The issue is discussed at length in the topic linked as a duplicate in the comments above -- [Firefox -moz-border-radius won't crop out image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image)

The best way around it is to use background images instead of foreground images where you want to have rounded corners:

ie: `<div style='background:url(myimage.jpg);' />` instead of `<img src='myimage.jpg'>`

The down-side of this is that background images aren't quite as flexible as foreground images -- ie its harder to scale them, etc. But it does resolve the problem.

The other options are to give the image itself rounded corners, or simply to ignore it (since it only affects Firefox 3; depends on how many of your users would be affected, and how much if affects your design).

Comment: thanks 4 answer / but i can not use back image / because i am using a component in my project that needs image element , because we can use some codes in imageUrl for getting images from database ... i am so depressed for radus in ff3...

Comment: I think the lesson to be learned here is that browser makers put vendor prefixes like `-moz-` on CSS features for a reason. That reason is that they know the feature is not 100% ready for use, so there will be issues like this. FF4 doesn't have the vendor prefix, so it can be assumed that they've ironed out these issues, but FF3 does, so you must assume that it has bugs.