# Chrome image border around rounded corners disappearing

Tags: google-chrome, rounded-corners, css

So, this is the problem: http://bildr.no/view/927562

A closer look: http://bildr.no/view/927563

As you can see, the border for each corner turns invisible. This is the CSS code for the image:

```
#contentImage {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

`<img src="images/image.jpg" id=contentImage" />`

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated :-)

Comment: Is your image cropped to have a rounded corner? It looks like the image is overlaying the corner.

Comment: Possible answer here. Look at the link in the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image

Comment: No, I thought chrome automatically took care of the cropping to be honest. Firefox seems to :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an unfortunate webkit bug. The only workaround that I know about is converting your img into a div and then putting the img as a background image:

```
#contentImage {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/100x100') top left no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybPKJ/

Comment: I was afraid of that :p Guess I'll have to clutter my css file then (have a lot of images).

Comment: If that's your case, then it will be more clean to add more markup instead of cluttering your css: http://jsfiddle.net/v9NVV/

Comment: I did just that, and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!