# Rounded corners with HTML "draggable"

Tags: css, html, draggable, rounded-corners

I am using the "draggable" attribute and find not all browsers render the element the same way while it is being dragged. Specifically, the background color sometimes is taken from the parent element (e.g. Chromium 33), and sometimes uses white (e.g. Firefox 28).

```html
<div style="background-color: #79a; padding: 4px;">
  <div style="border-radius: 12px; padding: 12px; background-color: #ead;" draggable='true' ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'This text may be dragged')">
    <p>Some content here that should have clean rounded corners while being dragged</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See above at http://jsfiddle.net/pZv35/3/.

Is there some way (preferably using CSS) to mitigate this problem?

Comment: You should get your example working before posting a question. jQuery UI isn't being loaded in your fiddle so the problem doesn't display there.

Comment: @matthew: the `draggable` attribute is not a jQueryUI property but part of the HTML5 spec - browsers that support it allow for nearly-any element to be dragged natively: no jQuery required at all. The fiddle works.

Comment: My mistake. I don't think you can style elements while they are being dragged using HTML5.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Adding `position: relative;` to `.inner` fixes this as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/pZv35/4/

Edit: I updated it to include `opacity: 0.999` as per Rutger's solution below: https://jsfiddle.net/vzcbng7w/8/

Comment: Works great. But why?

Comment: I suspect that it's a bug in webkit. There was a similar bug (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108079) filed about a year ago (now fixed) that mentioned that draggable elements' borders did not work as expected.

Comment: @igor did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @denski nope :(

Comment: @igor I dropped a fix in an answer below.

Answer (score 42):

Updated fix. Pain in the ...

Hopefully, this will help someone. The solution is from the `react-dnd` github.

**Add `transform: translate(0, 0);` to the node you wish to drag as a preview.**

> CSS in JS: `transform: 'translate(0, 0)'`

Solution from [here](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/788).

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I also had to remove `box-shadow` to remove the unrounded effect from the bottom corners.

Comment: OMG, thank you for this, this would have taken forever to figure out!

Comment: Based on the answer above - all I needed to add was `translate-x-0` to the draggable node `className`.

Answer (score 11):

This is still broken in Chrome (71). I found that this can be fixed by setting an opacity to the draggable element. If you do not desire opacity, you can set `opacity: 0.999;` to fix this.

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/8ro46wf7/

Answer (score 0):

For images, this did not work for me in present-day Chrome.  I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693620/1577662) works well for images.

Here's my code that's working today:

In css:

```
.content {
  background: url('') top left no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.999;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

in html:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="drag1" class="content" style="background:url('##POPULATED PROGRAMMATICALLY##');
   height:144px; width:144px;" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> </div>
</div>
```