# Corners vanish when I set a border-radius

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

The following code:

```
app = QApplication([])
mainWindow = QMainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
textEdit = QTextEdit()
mainWindow.setCentralWidget(textEdit)

app.setStyleSheet("""
QTextEdit
{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
""")
app.exec_()
```

Produces this result:

[image]

Weirdly, if I set a background color, the corners show up as expected:

[image]

The corners show up fine in both cases when I remove the border-radius, and *even more bizarrely*, I can actually quick-fix this by setting background-color: white. The margin has no bearing on the issue, I just set that so the problem would be easier to see. What's going on here? It seems similar to the CSS/webkit problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693437/chrome-image-border-around-rounded-corners-disappearing).

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the issue on with PyQt 5.6 and I guess it's a bug.

Seems like `QTextEdit` has a white background rectangle by default and this is drawn **over** the background that is specified in the stylesheet if there is no background color given in the stylesheet, but it is not drawn if a background color is specified in the stylesheet.

Why this is so, I don't know. We could check the [Qt sources](http://wiki.qt.io/Get_The_Source) and/or report a bug there.

But you also already found a workaround (specifying the background-color as white or whatever you like it to be), so I recommend to do that.