# CSS, rounded corners not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have two pictures on top of each other:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="picture">
         <span class="name"><br/><a  href="profile.php">Pavadinimas</a></span>
         <div class="picture-content">
              <div class="icons">
                   <div class="ico-info"><img src="images/product_mark_1.png" />
                        <span class="ico-info">Automatinis mechanizmas</span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="ico-info"><img class="ico-info" src="images/product_mark_2.png" />
                        <span class="ico-info">Miegamas mechanizmas</span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="ico-info"><img src="images/product_mark_3.png" /><br/>
                       <span class="info">Spyruoklės</span>
                </div>  
             </div>
             <div class="picture-grey"><img alt="" src="images/grey.png" />
             </div>
        </div>
             <div class="picture-photo"><img alt="" src="images/pic.png" />
                    <div class="description1">
                    Ilgis/Plotis/Aukštis
                    </div>
                    <div class="description2">
                    Ilgis/Plotis
                    </div>
                    <div class="description3">
                    300/300/300
                    </div>
                    <div class="description4">
                    miegamoji dalis 100/100
                   </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

I want the image at the top to be with rounded corners like this:

[image]

My css classes is:

```
.picture{ 
    position:relative; 
    width:400px; 
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:48px;
    margin-right:35px;
    margin-bottom:90px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.picture-content{ 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0px; 
    width:360px; 
    height:211px;
}

.picture-grey{
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:-65px; 
    left:15px; 
    height:243px;
    width:407px; 
    float:left;
}

.picture-photo{
    position:absolute; 
    width:380px; 
    height:223px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top:0px; left:0px; 
}
```

But unfortunately rounded corners is not working at all! Why not? Is there some issue I don't know?

Comment: Which browsers have you tested it with?

Comment: Just in case it's a mistake, note that you have 50px for `-moz` and 20px for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a old problem with firefox (and probably a few other browsers as well); it didn't crop the images until the latest firefox version:

[Firefox -moz-border-radius won't crop out image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347796/firefox-moz-border-radius-wont-crop-out-image)

Just out of curiosity, can you try the following?:

```
.picture{ 
position:relative; 
width:462px; 
height:305px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mOg.png') no-repeat; 
background-position:50% 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-khtml-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}

<div class="picture"></div>
```

I have the latest version of firefox so I can't check if it works on older versions as well, but it would make sense if it did. Firefox has been able to crop divs for quite some time.

Answer (score 4):

you want your image round! not DIV!

```
.picture-photo img {
    width:380px; 
    height:223px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! But it's still not working.. :( maybe something else wrong also?

Comment: which browser do you use? I already tests it, and it works well!

Comment: I think this has to be a browser issue. If using Internet Explorer, you have to keep in mind that border-radius doesn't work with IE versions prior to 9.0.

Comment: I'm using firefox 3.6 version

Comment: For firefox it works well! I recommence you, If you want to check your stylesheet on firefox, you should use Firebug. If your style have overwrite by other style, you can see it.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate answer, as long as the container `.picture-photo` wraps tight around the image (no visible padding), you can add the following CSS to hide the corners that are sticking out from the child element (the image):

```
.picture-photo {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```