# rounded corners to a div in firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox, html, rounded-corners

I want to add rounded corners to my div in firefox.
Ive tried:

```
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
```

and its not working.

Pls, does anyone have any alternative solutions?

Thanks

Comment: u can find answer here  

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163360/css-rounded-corners-not-working

Comment: I think you need space after vendor prefix

Comment: What specific version of Firefox are you testing against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

newer versions of firefox support simply

```
border-radius: 20px;
```

Did you try that?
Otherwise I'll need to see some more of your css.

Comment: @DAViD If you find one of the answers here solves your problem you should consider accepting it by ticking off the check-mark to the left of that answer.

Comment: @jack. Thanks. I didn't know or realize that.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the below three in your css

```
-moz-border-radius: 20px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
border-radius: 20px;
```

Some older versions use -moz and -webkit , but recent browser releases adopt CSS3 way of styling.

source : http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/

Answer (score 0):

As @vidiya mentioned

always make sure you cover all your basis:

```
-moz-border-radius: 20px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
border-radius: 20px;
```

i'd suggest looking at `LESS` or `SASS` so that you can then use mixins (functions within CSS)

```
 //From LESS
.rounded (@round:"4px") {
    -moz-border-radius: @round; 
    -webkit-border-radius: @round; 
    border-radius: @round; 
}
```